# How to resolve unmet dependencies of gnuplot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, aptitude, dependencies

I'm on an ubuntu 17.10 machine

`sudo apt upgrade` gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnuplot-x11 : Depends: gnuplot-data (= 5.0.7+dfsg1-1) but 4.6.6-3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt -f install` gives me the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/
gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmf /tex/latex/gnuplot/
gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex', which is also in package  
gnuplot-tex 4.6.6-3 Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache /apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb E: 
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg  returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo aptitude install gnuplot-x11` gives me the following:

```
The following packages will be upgraded: 
gnuplot-data 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  gnuplot gnuplot-x11 
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 292 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/60,4 kB of archives. After unpacking 45,1 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 677649 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnuplot-data (5.0.7+dfsg1-1) over (4.6.6-3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/gnuplot/gnuplot-lua-tikz-common.tex', which is also in package gnuplot-tex 4.6.6-3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnuplot-data_5.0.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Processing triggers for tex-common (6.09) ...
Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gnuplot:
 gnuplot depends on gnuplot-qt | gnuplot-x11 | gnuplot-nox; however:
  Package gnuplot-qt is not installed.
  Package gnuplot-x11 is not configured yet.
  Package gnuplot-nox is not installed.
  Package gnuplot-x11 which provides gnuplot-nox is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnuplot (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gnuplot
```

Comment: Fill a bugreport: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs